# Set default magic type for react echarts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, diagram, echarts

```
 toolbox: {
                feature: {
                    restore: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    magicType: {
                        show: true,
                        type: ['line', 'bar']
                    },
```

This configuration by default renders a line graph and allows for switching to the bar via click on the bar icon in the toolbox.
But what if I want the default selected type to be bars?

The actual issue Im having actually is that I want the default graph to be lines, like it is, BUT the line icon IS NOT rendering as selected (highlighted blue), rather it looks unselected.

If I click the line graph, even though it already was line graph, the icon becomes highlighted blue and the graph stays the same.

How can I make the icon be blue from the get go to emphasize the default selected type?